# Init external plugin in Angular (4) app

Tags: javascript, angular, nicescroll

how can I use external plugin in angular 4 app? I need use niceScroll plugin for scrollable div, which is represented by component.

```
<div class="d-flex" id="scrollable">
    <app-threads-list></app-threads-list>
</div>
```

I call nicescroll init function on element with id scrollable, from component **threads-list** like that:

```
$('#scrollable').niceScroll();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are trying to use jquery in Angular .

Without typings
**Step One**

```
npm install jquery --save
```

**Step two**

```
Add the jquery scripts file in .angular-cli.json file


"scripts": [ "../node_modules/jquery/src/jquery-min.js" ]
```

**Step three**

```
Adding a var in component to be used as a global variable
```

**//using external js modules in Angular**

```
declare var $: any;


Then in ngAfterViewInit(){
  $('#scrollable').niceScroll();
}
```

Check this link for more info [**LINK**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq) with and without typings